# Null values for PageMediaSize of a PrintTicket with Adobe PDF Creator using custom page size

Tags: wpf, pdf, printing

I'm writing a WPF application to get and save print profiles (and another application using this print profiles to print documents).

It works fine except when I try to use Adobe PDF Creator has a printer with custom size (like 800mm by 1200mm). Then the PageMediaSize Width and Height are null in the print ticket.

Here's the code I use to get the PrintTicket :

```
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrintPage += (o, a) =>
            {
                PrintQueue pq = pd.PrintQueue;
                PrintTicket ticket = pd.PrintTicket;
                ...
                a.Cancel = true;
            };
            doc.Print();
        }
```

The PrindDialog contains the correct width and height for the page, but if I try to use the PrintTicket to print a document it crash, stating that PageMediaSize  cannot contains null values.

Anyone have an idea on how to get a working PrintTicket ?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a problem with Adobe PDF Creator's driver.  The driver provides values for all the sizes, so if there is a problem, you might want to contact the makers of the printer/driver.

A way around this would be to figure out the sizes (800mm x 1200mm) and assume a resolution of 1/96 inches.  Then do a conversion:

```
Width:  ( 800mm) / (25.4 mm/in) / (1/96in) = 3023.62
Height: (1200mm) / (25.4 mm/in) / (1/96in) = 4535.43
```

And with those values you can say:

```
pd.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(Width, Height);
```